# Как правильно составить запрос на извлечение данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть две таблицы: `Good(name, id)` и `GoodHasAttribute(good_id, attribute_id, value)`.
В таблице `GoodHasAttribute` хранятся значения атрибутов для каждого товара.
Мне нужно извлечь товары с указанными свойствами. В настоящий момент есть следующий запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM Good t
JOIN GoodHasAttribute goodAttributes ON   
(`goodAttributes`.`good_id`=`t`.`id`) and 
(
((goodAttributes.attribute_id=1) AND (goodAttributes.value LIKE '%белый%')) or
((goodAttributes.attribute_id=3) AND (goodAttributes.value LIKE '%красный%'))
)
```

Он возвращает мне только те товары, в которых есть хотя бы один атрибут, но мне нужно с обеими.

Пока что придумал убрать группировку условий и `or` заменить на `and`, но в таком случае я также получу товары с атрибутами "`attribute_id=1, value=красный`" и "`attribute_id=3, value=белый`".

Какой запрос извлечет нужные мне данные?

Comment: @co11ter, что-нибудь типа

     select * from good t join GoodHasAttribute ga1 on t.id=ga1.good_id 
       join GoodHasAttribute ga2 on t.id=ga2.good_id
       where 
         ga1.attribute_id=1 and ga1.value like '%белый%' and 
         ga2.attribute_id=3 and ga2.value like '%красный%';

Comment: @co11ter, потому как не может одно поле (attribute_id) иметь одновременно значение 1 и 3. Значит, Вам нужны разные строки из GoodHasAttribute, соответственно для запроса это таблица с разными алиасами.

Answer (score 1):

надо использовать два *join*-а. примерно так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c26f/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table g (id int, n text);
insert into g values
   (1, "товар1")
  ,(2, "товар2")
;

create table a (id int, g int, v text);
insert into a values
   (1, 1, "белый")
  ,(3, 1, "красный")
  ,(1, 2, "серый")
  ,(3, 2, "зелёный")
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
 from g
join a a1
 on a1.g = g.id and a1.id = 1 and a1.v like "%белый%"
join a a2
 on a2.g = g.id and a2.id = 3 and a2.v like "%красный%"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c26f/2/0)**:

```
| id |      n | id | g |     v | id | g |       v |
|----|--------|----|---|-------|----|---|---------|
|  1 | товар1 |  1 | 1 | белый |  3 | 1 | красный |
```